# What is the proper way to pass a ThreadFunction to CreateThread API

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

Definitions first:

```
uses
  Windows;

type
  TThreadParams = record
    FParam1 : Integer;
    FParam2 : array [0..511] of Byte;
  end;

  TFoo = class
  private
    FThreadHandle: THandle;
    FThreadID : Cardinal;
    FSomeParameters: TThreadParams;

    function procInObject(const Params: Pointer): DWord; stdcall;
  public
    procedure CreateObjThread;
  end;

function procInInterface(const Params: Pointer): DWord; stdcall;

implementation

function procInInterface(const Params: Pointer): DWord;
begin
  Result := High(Cardinal);

  while True do
  begin
    //Do something with Params
  end;
end;

{ TFoo }

procedure TFoo.CreateObjThread;
begin
  FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @procInInterface, @FSomeParameters, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);

  //FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @procInObject, Self, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);
end;

function TFoo.procInObject(const Params: Pointer): DWord;
begin
  Result := High(Cardinal);

  while True do
  begin
    //Do something with Params
  end;
end;
```

Now, as you can see I'm trying to create an anonymous thread with WinAPI. I don't want to use TThread class or some libraries like Omni.

The problem is when I do

```
procedure TFoo.CreateObjThread;
begin
  FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @procInInterface, @FSomeParameters, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);

  //FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @procInObject, Self, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);
end;
```

code compiles and when I do

```
procedure TFoo.CreateObjThread;
begin
  //FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @procInInterface, @FSomeParameters, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);

  FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @procInObject, Self, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);
end;
```

it doesn't. Compiler says "[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(45): E2036 Variable required". So a question arises; Do I have to use some methods declared in Unit interface rather than a class of an object, in order to achive what I want? What are the catches those make **procInInterface** a variable and **procInObject** doesn't?

On the other hand it was able to compile

```
procedure TFoo.CreateObjThread;
begin    
  FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @TFoo.procInObject, Self, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);
end;
```

but this seems inappropriate to me. Does this way causes to all instances of TFoo using same code block for **procInObject** rather then having their own code block? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Instance methods are actually backed by 2 pointers. One for the method AND one for the instance itself. `CreateThread` takes a single pointer directly to the thread function for the `lpStartAddress`. Fortunately you can easily use `lpParameter` to get back to an object. (Something `TThread` et. al. do for you already.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong in thinking that it is inappropriate, or wrong, for multiple threads to run the same code block.  That is absolutely fine and is often done.  Code, (unless self-modifying) is intrisically thread-safe.

Not sure why you need a separate record/class for the thread params, rather than simply using fields of TFoo, but I guess it's your design:).

Cast the parameter in 'ProcInInterface' back to a TFoo and you should be OK.

You probably realize that you need to be careful about freeing TFoo, either ensuring that the thread is terminated, (maybe in its d'tor), or never explicitly freeing it and allowing the OS to terminate it at app close.

What do you have against the TThread class, (apart from the horrible synchronize/WaitFor/OnTerminate that you do not have to use)?

Comment: The real problem is the attempt to use procInObject.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - well, yes, I would have created the thread in the TFoo ctor, but I thought that posting too much advice would just cloud the issue at this stage.

Comment: My approach was object ownering the thread itself, but researching this kind of anonymous threading and support from this community it turns out otherwise, but, not a ownering-like but accessing. Techniques and actual concepts will settle in time. After further researching and code reading, especially TThread, it reveals me that a proc that handles a thread code or a proc which is calling an object's code that meant to be a thread code in generalism approach is the general way it goes. My obstacle was why I couldn't be able to use as @procInObject, and Mr. Heffernan's answer's lit the thing...

Comment: @The_aLiEn - you're at least half way there:)  One of the biggest problems I've had is deleteing such objects that are threaded internally and so destruction is non-trivial and often asynchronous two-phase, eg: 'DestroyYourself(TNotifyEvent:OnDestructionComplete);'. These subsystems are good fun though, and useful:)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an instance method because it is the wrong type. Your attempts to use `procInObject` can never work.

A thread procedure is a plain flat procedure that is not a method of a class. In order to get the instance into your thread you need to pass it using the Params arguments.

The thread function looks like this:

```
function ThreadProc(Params: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  Obj: TFoo;
begin
  Obj := TFoo(Params);
  ....
end;
```

The procedure can now call methods on `Obj`.

The call to `CreateThread`:

```
procedure TFoo.CreateObjThread;
begin    
  FThreadHandle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @ThreadProc, Self, CREATE_SUSPENDED, FThreadID);
end;
```

Comment: '@' is unsafe?  I don't disbelieve you, but why?

Comment: @Martin because it returns an untyped pointer. So you bypass the ability for the compiler to check that function signatures match. The RTL fails to declare proper function types in its winapi translations. But if you provide your own you can then be typesafe. Which would stop the user committing the mistake shown in this question. Always better to find out errors at compile time.

Comment: Ah.. OK, yes, there is that :)

Comment: You should also prefer `BeginThread` over `CreateThread` as the RTL will enable the multithreaded heap flag when `BeginThread` is used, but not with a direct call to `CreateThread`.